# How to make this as block elements?

Tags: html, css

The below code acts like a table perfectly. When I shrink the page, I want it to first name-foo first and below that last name - foo last. I am stuck here. I understand that I need to use "@media 
only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)" here. But I am lost after that. Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="Main">
    <section id="sub">
        <div>First Name</div>
        <div>Last Name</div>
        <div>Middle Name</div>
    </section>
    <section id="sub2">
        <div>foo first</div>
        <div>foo Last</div>
        <div>foo Middle</div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can modify your HTML like below.  Make all the div elements float left with a fixed width of 49% or 50%.  The it would float side by side when it has space and the second div would wrap down when there is not enough space to float by the side.  Media queries might not be required in this case unless it is a design constraint for you.

Css here:
    #Main section div{float:left; width:50%;}
HTML here:

```
<div id="Main">
    <section id="sub">
        <div>First Name</div>
        <div>foo first</div>
    </section>
    <section id="sub1">
        <div>Last Name</div>
        <div>foo Last</div>
    </section>
    <section id="sub2">
        <div>Middle Name</div>
        <div>foo Middle</div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: You are right, that would work. But, I can't change my html. It's dynamic.